# Simplifying a function that has max and min expressions

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am trying to FIND under what conditions are the following functions equal

$$F(\alpha,\beta)= G(\alpha,\beta)\leftrightarrow F(\alpha,\beta)- G(\alpha,\beta)=0$$
where $$F(\alpha,\beta)= \max(1+\beta,\beta+\alpha)\tag1$$
$$G(\alpha,\beta)= 2\max(1-\alpha,\alpha,\beta)+2\min(\alpha,\beta)\tag2$$
$$\alpha,\beta>0 $$

So then what I need to do is take the difference between (1) and (2)
$$\max(1+\beta,\beta+\alpha) -2\max(1-\alpha,\alpha,\beta)-2\min(\alpha,\beta)=0$$

Can (3) be simplified so I can have a clean expression maybe without the max and min? Are there any properties of $\max,\min$ I can make use of?

Thanks

**Update** According to answer provided below the difference can be re-written as

$$ \frac{1+\alpha+2\beta}{2} + \frac{|\alpha-1|}{2} - 2 \left(\frac{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{|2\alpha-1|}{2}+\beta}{2}+\frac{|\beta-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{|2\alpha-1|}{2}|}{2}\right)-2 \left(\frac{\alpha+\beta}{2}-\frac{|\beta-\alpha|}{2}\right)$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**
$$\max \{a,b\}={a+b\over 2}+{\vert b-a\vert\over 2}$$
$$\min \{a,b\}={a+b\over 2}-{\vert b-a\vert\over 2}$$

Comment: Cool thanks that should help alot. Can I post the solution after this equality and then maybe you can correct me if I am wrong?

Comment: Oh btw I have also max between three expressions as you can see $\max(1-\alpha,\alpha,\beta)$ ?@Fermat

Comment: Why not? You can post your answer to your own question.

Comment: max(a,b,c)=max({a,b},c) and then use the above equality.

Comment: but what does it mean to have $\max({a,b},c)= \frac{\{a,b\}+c}{2}+\frac{|c-(a,b)|}{2}$? I mean it isn't clear to me how to mathematically manipulate.

Comment: $\max({a,b},c)= \frac{\max\{a,b\}+c}{2}+\frac{|c-\max\{a,b\}|}{2}$ where $\max \{a,b\}={a+b\over 2}+{\vert b-a\vert\over 2}$...

Comment: Oh I see thanks. @Fermat

Comment: Can you please confirm whether the solution I provided above is correct?

Comment: It seems to be correct but don't forget the expression is equal to zero... $$\frac{1+\alpha+2\beta}{2} + \frac{|\alpha-1|}{2} - 2 \left(\frac{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{|2\alpha-1|}{2}+\beta}{2}+\frac{|\beta-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{|2\alpha-1|}{2}|}{2}\right)-2 \left(\frac{\alpha+\beta}{2}-\frac{|\beta-\alpha|}{2}\right)=0$$

Comment: btw do you happen to have a proof to the hints you provided in your answer.

Comment: Let $a\ge b$. Then $${a+b\over 2}+{\vert b-a\vert\over 2}=a=\max \{a,b\}$$... If $a\le b$ then ...

Comment: @fermant thanks, does this apply for the case when $\max(a,b,c)$?

Comment: The equality $$
 
max\{a,b,c\}=max(\{a,b\},c)$$ is by definition. Once you proved the equality for $\max\{a,b\}$ you can combine it with this definition...