# Simplifying a function that has max

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have read in paper that the following 
$$f(\alpha)=max\{1,\alpha\} + \max\{\alpha+1, 2\alpha\} -\alpha +[1-\alpha]^+$$

where $[x]^+:=\max\{0,x\}$,
can be simplified to the following
$$f(\alpha)=3\max\{1,\alpha\} - \alpha$$

I have no clue why can anyone see where the trick is

Comment: Consider the cases $\alpha \leq 1$ and $\alpha \geq 1$ separately.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1195917/simplifying-a-function-that-has-max-and-min-expressions/1195928#1195928

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The maximum function has a "translation" property:

$$\max(a+c,b+c)=\max(a,b)+c.$$

You can apply it as $$\max(1+\alpha,2\alpha)=\max(1+\alpha,\alpha+\alpha)=\max(1,\alpha)+\alpha,$$ $$\max(1-\alpha,0)=\max(1-\alpha,\alpha-\alpha)=\max(1,\alpha)-\alpha.$$

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware of the translation property, are you aware of any relationship $\max\{a,b,c}$? and a relationship  $\max\{a,b\}= \frac{a+b}{2}+ \frac{|b-a|}{2}$?

Comment: The translation property obviously extends to any number of arguments. And using it, $\max(a,b)=\max(\frac{a+b}2+\frac{a-b}2,\frac{a+b}2-\frac{a-b}2)=\frac{a+b}2+max(\frac{a-b}2,-\frac{a-b}2)=\frac{a+b}2+\frac{|a-b|}2$.

Answer (score 1):

You can use $2max(a, b) = a + b + |a-b|$

$2max(1, a) + 2max(a+1, 2a) + 2max(1-a, 0) = 1 + a + |1-a|+a+1+2a+|a-1|+1-a+0+|1-a| = 3+3a+3|1-a|=3.2max(1,a)$

Answer (score 0):

$$
f(\alpha) = \left\{ \begin{array}{cl} 
1+(\alpha+1)-\alpha+(1-\alpha) = 3-\alpha & \text{ if } \alpha < 1 \\
\alpha + 2\alpha - \alpha + 0 = 2\alpha & \text{ if } \alpha \geq 1
\end{array} \right.
$$
$$
f(\alpha) = \left\{ \begin{array}{cl} 
 3-\alpha & \text{ if } \alpha < 1 \\
 3\alpha - \alpha & \text{ if } \alpha \geq 1
\end{array} \right. = 3\max(1,\alpha) - \alpha
$$

Answer (score 0):

Assume $\alpha\ge 1.$ Then

$$\begin{array}{rcl}f(\alpha) & = & \max\{1,\alpha\} + \max\{\alpha+1, 2\alpha\} -\alpha +[1-\alpha]^+ \\ & = & \alpha + 2\alpha-\alpha+0 \\ & = & 2\alpha \\ & = &3\max\{1,\alpha\} - \alpha.\end{array}$$

Can you do the same in case $\alpha \le 1?$